# Laravel 5, unprocessable entity 422 error

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I am trying to validate the login form and display errors on the page. But i am getting a 422 error when i click on login.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is my handleLogin function that handles the processes when login button is clicked.

```
public function handleLogin(Request $request){

    /* validate user */
   $this->validate($request, User::$login_validation_rules);

    $data = $request->only('email', 'password');
    if(\Auth::attempt($data)){
    return redirect()->route('home');
    }

return back()->withInput();
}
```

The following is the routes.php

```
Route::get('/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'LoginController@login']);
Route::post('/handleLogin', ['as' => 'handleLogin', 'uses' => 'LoginController@handleLogin']);
Route::get('/home', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'UsersController@home']);
Route::get('/logout', ['as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'LoginController@logout']);
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController', ['only' => ['create', 'store']]);
```

And the following is the login form.

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')

<h2> Login </h2>
@if(count($errors))
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif

    {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'handleLogin')) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('email') !!}
    {!! Form::text('email', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('password') !!}
  {!! Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
</div>
{!! Form::token() !!}
{!! Form::submit('Login', array('class' => 'btn btn-default')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}

@stop
```

Comment: Show the output of `dd($request, User::$login_validation_rules)`.

Comment: It displays a blank page ...

Comment: I hope you are trying it in `handleLogin` method.

Comment: yes, i have displayed that in the first line of the function, just tried, it doesn't work, just displays a blank page..

Comment: @Harsh 422 error returns when the validation fails. What rules are defined in `User::$login_validation_rules`

Comment: public static $login_validation_rules = [

        'email' => 'required|email|exists:users',
        'password' => 'required'
    ];